# Does $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sqrt{x}dx$ converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Does $\int_0^\infty  e^{-x}\sqrt{x}dx$ converge? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+of+e%5E%28-x%29*sqrt%28x%29) say's it's $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, so yes it converges.

Comment: Yes it is from http://goo.gl/XjATnA . If it is finite number. It converge. You can look more to integral itself : http://goo.gl/NINBF0 .

Comment: It's a value of the Gamma function, $\Gamma(\tfrac{3}{2})$. To me, an nice answer would be an argument why $\int_0^\infty {\mathrm e}^{-x}x^a\,{\mathrm d}x$ converges for any $a>0$. The problem is that the factorial already grows so fast, it's hard to find a reasonable upper bound. You can do integration under the integral tricks, but that raises more questions and hence isn't too smooth.

Comment: If in the integral it were x, rather than Sqrt[x], the integral would be the mean of the exponential distribution with parameter 1, which is known to have value 1. You can easily do that with integration by parts. Then, since Sqrt[x]<x, the value of the given integral has to be less than 1.

Comment: @NikolajK as $\frac{x^a}{e^x} \rightarrow 0$ (can be proven from Taylor series), it is monotonically decreasing and so the convergence of the integral can be checked by testing the convergence of $\sum_n n^a e^{-n}$. This converges due to ratio test.

Comment: @dalastboss: k, thx. Though I have no real intuition for the ratio test, I don't know if I consider that an argument. I mean we know it's true from the start and so we already know there is a proof when asking. The task is to get to the level where the opposite statement feels wrong :)

Comment: I didn't realize by "argument" you meant hand-wavy intuition rather than mathematical proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I don't know how to calculate the exact value, it is quite easy to show it does converge.
One basic fact in improper integrals is that, whether it converges or not depends completely on how the integrated function behaves at the "bad" points (say, infinity or points where the function is not defined) and has nothing to do with the "good" points.(where it is good defined)
For this function $f(x)=e^{-x} \sqrt {x}$, the only bad point is $+\infty$. All we have to do is take a look at
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt x}{e^x}$$
as $x\to +\infty$.
Review another famous fact that $\forall r \in \mathbb R^+$, however large,
$$\frac{x^r}{e^x} \to 0^+$$
as $x\to +\infty$
Therefore, we have good reason to claim that $\exists M \in R^+$ such that $\forall x>M$
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt x}{e^x}<\frac{1}{x^2}$$
Since
$$\int_{M}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\frac{1}{M}$$
We now obtain
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x} \sqrt {x} dx=\int_{0}^{M} e^{-x} \sqrt {x} dx+\int_{M}^{+\infty} e^{-x} \sqrt {x} dx<\int_{0}^{M} e^{-x} \sqrt {x} dx+\frac{1}{M}$$
And $\int_{0}^{M} e^{-x} \sqrt {x} dx$ is a proper integral, and $\frac{1}M$ is a given number, therefore $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x} \sqrt {x} dx$ converges.

Comment: nice proof (+1)

Answer (score 3):

set $u=\sqrt x$ then
$$...=\int_0^\infty 2u^2e^{-u^2}du=-\int_0^\infty u(-2ue^{-u^2})du.$$

Set $f'(u)=-2ue^{-u^2}$ and $g(u)=u$, and by part you'll get
$$-\int_0^\infty u(-2ue^{-u^2})du=\underbrace{-[ue^{-u^2}]_0^\infty}_{=0} +\int_0^{\infty }e^{-u^2}du$$

Now use the fact that $\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt \pi$ and that $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$
to conclude. But a way to prove is either to use polar coordinate on 
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
and take the square root to conclude, or you know that 
$$\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=1$$
(cf. normal law) then you make the substitution $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}x$ and remark that the function $u\mapsto e^{-u^2}$ is even to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

yes, $\sqrt{\pi}/2$ should be your answer. let $\sqrt{x}=t$ make the substitution, then integrate by parts. you'll get an integral involving $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt$ which is equal to the answer stated above.

you should integrate the resulting integral, i.e., $2\int_{0}^\infty t^2\,e^{-t^2}\,dt$ by parts by breaking it up as $t$ $\cdot$ $2te^{-t^2}$ (I didn't want to give away all the tricks).

Comment: It should be a comment, not an answer !

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. How did you calculated this? I am interested in whole solution.

Comment: wrong, if $t=\sqrt x$ then $x=t^2$ and thus $dx=2tdt$, finally, you get $\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-t^2}dt$ and not $\int_0^\infty  e^{-t^2}dt$ !

Comment: Okey, I substitiuted $\sqrt{x} = t$. Now I don't know how to resolve that integral $2\int_0^\infty t^{2}e^{-t^{2}}$. I hope there's no mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $\sqrt xe^{-x}$is monotonically decreasing for large enough $x$ and as such the integral converges only if the infinite sum of the same converges. Then apply ratio test.

Comment: Your hint is not true in general, is it? You can make it true by e.g. requiring that the integrand be monotonic. (This particular integrand is not monotonic, but it _is_ monotonic for sufficiently large $x$, which is good enough.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I forgot to include this hypothesis.